# Can i post Retrofit @Path and @Field in the same time?

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I try to post

```
public interface Service  {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/mobile/seeker/Search/JobsInCompany/{id}")
    Call<retrofit_companyList.Contributor> JobBKK_POST (@Path("id") String IdCompany,
                                                        @Field("token") String token,
                                                        @Field("page") String page);

}

StartRetrofit(){

        Retrofit_Build Build = new Retrofit_Build();

        Service connect = Build.retrofit.create(Service.class);

        Call<retrofit_companyList.Contributor> call = connect.POST(
                IDCompany,
                Token,
                Integer.toString(Page)
                );

        call.enqueue(new Callback<retrofit_companyList.Contributor>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<retrofit_companyList.Contributor> response, Retrofit retrofit) {...}
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Retrofit Fail : " + t.toString());
            });
}
```

**And then this's log**

> **D/OkHttp: --> POST /mobile/sample/JobsInCompany/50357  HTTP/1.1**
>
> **D/OkHttp: token=XXXXX & page=1**
>
> D/OkHttp: --> END POST (45-byte body)
>
> **D/OkHttp: --> POST /mobile/sample/JobsInCompany/  HTTP/1.1**
>
> **D/OkHttp: token=XXXXX & page=1**
>
> D/OkHttp: --> END POST (45-byte body)
>
> D/OkHttp: <-- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (171ms)
>
> D/OkHttp: Server: nginx
>
> V/Fragment_choose_company: Retrofit Success Runnable : Total list : 11
>
> V/Fragment_choose_company: Retrofit Success Runnable : RTC company,co
>   and https://XXX/images/503571.jpg
>
> V/Fragment_choose_company: Retrofit Success Runnable : Total list : 20
>
> V/Fragment_choose_company: Retrofit Success Runnable : null and null

**This is problem I was called only one time. But retrofit was posted 2 time and data response was null**

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

Yes, but it cause logical error as your see.

As you see in your logs retrofit was posted 2 times. But result is not exactly as your expect

**Cause:**

1.There are two MIME types that HTML forms use:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data

2.In Retrofit:

- **@Field**: mean Named pair for a form-encoded request
- **@Part**: Denotes a single part of a multi-part request

So Retrofit understand you want to create 2 POST request: form-encoded and multi-part. That explain why you see in log it post two times.

Answer (score 0):

@NguyenDat explained why you cannot use it. I had same problem. I have tried with two @Path. Same Problem.

What solved problem to me was: @Path and @Query combination .